# Math Expressions on computer vs iPhone displayed differently

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app, mathjax

I use the Mathematics and Mathematica sites sometimes, to ask questions displayed in nice mathematical textbook script.  In the following screenshot from iPhone you can see that math expression is shown in code.  I think it is Mathjax.

In any case, when on my computer I see the nice type script without the code.  Is it possible to see nice typescript on my iPhone?  Or is this reserved for computers only?

[image]

Comment: small quibble - these are not forums